# Reading BMP 32 bits

Tags: c++, file, struct, bmp

I try to read a bitmap file(32 bits). This my program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <string>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;

#pragma pack(1)
struct header
{
    int16_t header;
    int32_t filesize;
    int16_t reser;
    int16_t reser1;
    int32_t dataoffset;
};

struct infoheader
{
    int32_t headersize;
    int32_t width;
    int32_t height;
    int16_t plans;
    int16_t bpp;
    int32_t compression;
    int32_t datasize;
    int32_t re;
    int32_t ve;
    int32_t color;
    int32_t importantcolor;
};


struct  PIxel
{
    unsigned char G;
    unsigned char B;
    unsigned char R;
    unsigned char A;
};





int main()
{
    cout << 1 << " ";
    header h;
    infoheader info;
    PIxel* p;
    string name;
    getline(cin, name);

    ifstream file(name, ios::binary);
    if (file.is_open())
    {

        cout << "true" << endl;
        file.read((char*)&h, sizeof(h));
        if (h.header == 0x4D42)
        {
            cout << 1 << endl;
            file.read((char*)&info, sizeof(info));
            cout << info.width << " " << info.height << " " << h.filesize << " " << info.bpp << endl;
           // int pa = 3;
            cout << info.bpp << endl;
            int size = info.width * info.height * info.bpp / 8 ;
            char* arr = new char[size];
            file.read(arr, size);
            char* temp = arr;

            int sizep = info.height * info.width;
            p = new PIxel[sizep];

            for (int i = info.height - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < info.width; j++)
                {
                    //temp++;
                    int index = i * info.width + j;
                    p[index].A = *(temp++);
                    p[index].B = *(temp++);
                    p[index].G = *(temp++);
                    p[index].R = *(temp++);


                }
             // temp += 1;
            }


            HWND consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
            HDC hdc = GetDC(consoleWindow);
            for (int i = 0; i < info.height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < info.width; j++)
                {
                    int index = i * info.width + j;
                    PIxel m = p[index];
                    SetPixel(hdc, j, i, RGB( m.A,m.R, m.G, m.B));


                }
            }
            ReleaseDC(consoleWindow, hdc);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << 0;
        }
    }
}
```

It works but the image on my console is not right...
[image]
Input image:
[image]

I do not know what is the actual role of alpha,adding transparency to Bitmap images is not as easy as it sounds. Transparent Bitmaps are not supported by all the applications.
Can you help me to fix it and explain the actual role of alpha?

Comment: I think the order of the colors is Alpha, Green, Red, Blue.  
Your order is Alpha, Blue, Green, Red  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#/media/File:BitfieldsSLN.svg